# How to tell Grafana using OAuth that some user is admin or belong to some org?

Tags: oauth-2.0, grafana, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have CF UAA and try to use it with Grafana 4.0.2 through generic_oauth. I was able to configure login etc. and it works fine. What I'm missing is how to differentiate admin user between others. Also, I would like to differentiate users into separate organizations in Grafana.

Is it doable? If so, how? I was looking at https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/#user-info **/userinfo** endpoint (it is used in my Grafana generic_oauth setup) and it looks like it doesn't have enough information. Maybe this can be done somehow through scopes?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for the same issue. I will checkout if creating a plugin like @AussieDan suggested is the right way for that.

Comment: @MikaAndrianarijaona any luck? I'm just curious at this point

Answer (score 4):

The generic oauth plugin doesn't provide a way to automatically add the user to a particular org or to designate their level of access.

Once the user has successfully authenticated to Grafana you can edit their user account and set their permission level etc.

It would be possible to extend the `BasicUserInfo` struct returned by the oauth modules to be able to hold a list of orgs the user should be a member of, and to update `login_oauth.go` to manage the user's org memberships if that element was returned by the oauth plugin.  At that point it looks like the simplest approach would be to create an `oauth_cloudfoundry` plugin that could use the cloudfoundry group memberships to map to grafana org memberships.

Comment: Do you know if Grafana has any kind of hook or clean way to do what you suggest?

Comment: The clean way to do it is to implement a Grafana oauth plugin, which isn't too complicated.

Comment: As reference, I'd suggest having a look here for more info regarding organisation and roles per user: https://community.grafana.com/t/which-fields-are-expected-in-userinfo/1807

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to explicitly create a user in Grafana and then set him/her as admin in some org before the first OAuth login. Look at this post for more details:  https://medium.com/@davidoha/how-to-restrict-user-access-with-to-grafana-with-generic-oauth-656a1a660a7b